# Find nearby rectangles on X-Y plane

Tags: java, algorithm, user-interface, search, shapes

[image]

I have few rectangles on an x-y plane.There is a reference rectangle . The reference rectangle's position is changeable. I need efficient way to find the

- first rectangle that is found on the LEFT side of the reference rectangle.
- first rectangle that is found on the RIGHT side of the reference rectangle.
- first rectangle that is found on the TOP side of the reference rectangle.
- first rectangle that is found on the BOTTOM side of the reference rectangle.

Pseudo-code or Java code is fine. 
**Emphasis is given on the faster code than space consumed .**
Solving one side will solve the other 3 sides. 
Let's say, **we need to find the list of nearest rectangles that fall on the left side of the "REFERENCE RECT" .** 
The "REFERENCE RECT" is movable. 
All other rectangles are stationary at the time of calculating.

**PS. Each box can be the "REFERENCE RECT". Boxes are added to the X-Y plane one at a time.**

Comment: Please specify more in detail what exactly is "first rectangle that is found on the LEFT side of the reference rectangle." From that it could mean at least 4 differnet things.

Comment: If I'm coding to spec, I usually expect to be paid for my time. Put less snarkily, this is a *help* site, not a *do-your-homework-for-you* site. Show us code, tell us the problems you're having.

Comment: If you are aware about the concept of linked list, you could use that. Along with the nextNode and previousNode in a linked list, you add a upperNode and lowerNode also.

Comment: What are you trying to do? explain in terms of the image you just added

Comment: I need to find the find the nearest rectangle on left side of reference rect. it can be a list of rectangles if they all are nearest to the reference rectangle. similarly on other sides can be calculated.

Comment: @ dcsohl , Its not a home work that you solve for money. Its a real world problem. And I am asking the right community who might help with algorithm / idea or code . If you think you have an idea to solve it , you are most welcome.

Comment: it could be a bit tedious to implement, but linked list could help you here.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like an R-Tree or, possibly, Quad tree.

Comment: It depends on true requirements - which despite lots of bold text, the OP has not made clear. For example, will boxes change over time? (= Would it be feasible to calculate once and look things up ever after?) Will there be truly humongous amounts of boxes? How many times will each box-scape be queried? All of these would influence the "best" alternative.

Comment: Yes boxes will change over time, but not at the time of calculating nearest LEFT ,RIGHT....

Answer (score 2):

This pseudo-code may not be fast during setup (O(N^2)), but once `NearestBoxes` has been built, it will beat anything else (since it won't have to recalculate anything). Beware of typos - I haven't tested this.

```
public enum RPos { Up, Down, Left, Right };

public class Box {
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;        
    boolean isRelative(b, RPos rp) {
       // returns true if b can be said to be "rp" 
       // (say, left) of this box
    }
    double dist(Box b, RPos rp) {
       // assumes non-overlapping
       // add some simple trig here:
       //   if boxes adjacent in chosen direction, distance 
       //      (if Right, then x2-p.x1, ...)
       //   if boxes not adjacent, then euclidean distance between 
       //   nearest corners.
    }
}

class NearestBoxes {    

    HashMap<RPos, HashMap<Box, TreeMap<Double, ArrayList<Box>>>> 
        = new HashMap<>();

    public NearestBoxes(List<Box> boxes) {
       for (RPos rp : RPos.values) {
          nearest.put(rp, 
             new HashMap<Box, TreeMap<Double, ArrayList<Box>>>();
          for (Box a : boxes) {
             TreeMap<Double, ArrayList<Box>> n = 
                new TreeMap<Double, ArrayList<Box>>());
             nearest.get(rp).put(a, n);                    
             for (Box b : boxes) {
                 if (a.isRelative(b, rp)) {
                    double d = a.dist(b, rp);                        
                    if (d == n.firstKey()) {
                       n.get(d).add(b);
                    } else if (d < n.firstKey()) {
                       n.put(d, new ArrayList());
                       n.get(d).add(b);
                    }
                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }

    public List<Box> getNearest(Box b, RPos rp) {
       TreeMap<Double, ArrayList<Box>> n = nearest.get(rp).get(b);
       return (n.isEmpty()) ? new ArrayList<Box>() 
                            : n.get(n.firstKey());           
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks . Each box's LEFT,RIGHT,TOP&BOTTOM will have a sorted map  of minimum distanced lists of boxes. Only thing is that for each box move we need to change this index....

Comment: And that is why I asked in comments if boxes would move at all, or if there would be lots (as in 1k+) of them. If there are many boxes, or they move move frequently, then you should build yourself an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) - but either you find a good pre-existing library, or be prepared for substantial coding.

Answer (score 2):

**Feel free to comment and show logic depicting that it can produce false positive.**

**The key concept of searching in Nearest Neighbour Search is to split the domain to minimize searching and quit the search as early as the nearest neighbour is found.**

Assuming that the boxes have an id and they have x,y coordinates.
I want to utilize the x-y coordinate information to find the nearest rect. 
This solution initially splits the whole x-y plane into considerably  smaller domain to search in .[image]

***Solve LEFT:***

The equation of vertical lines are x=b.Save the right edge of each rectangle as they are added to the x-y plane. `TreeMap<Integer x,ArrayList<Integer>> rightEdgeMap;`
The value `ArrayList<Integer>` holds ids of boxes,
So the search domain is dramatically decreased.
Now split and search in the decreased X-Y plane marked with ***blue*** color, untill the nearest rect is found.

***How to search?***

Make a searching bounding box and consider it to be grow-able on X-Y plane.
Since any right edge falling within the height of the reference rect is the nearest possibility, start searching there.[ Look at the first searching box in the image ].

search only within the new growth of the searching box. If more than one rect found in searching box, measure distance:

- If the right edge falls within the height of the referenceRect, take horizontal distance from referenceRect or searchingBoxRightEdge.

  - Other wise take distance from the bottom of the edge to the nearest corner of the referenceRect.

  Alternatively, for simplicity you can accept the highest x valued edge within the the searching box. For fine grained solution, use above 2 methods.

Flatten the searching box by adding 1/5th of smallest box pixels on x axis and  y axis until any axis or both of them are reached to the end.  1/5th is an assumption , it can be solid 20 or 30 pixels  . 
 The constraint is to add same amount of pixels on both x and y axis in searching box. Taking too many pixels will result in searching longer and wait longer to finish calculation.
You don't need to flatten the searching box after the first match, since that's the END of searching.

When any box is resized or adding a new box, update  `rightEdgeMap` appropriately. 
You will need another `map<Integer,Integer> boxIdToRightEdgeMap;` where key is id of box and value is the `rightEdge` x value.
Whenever adding a new box/resize is done on any box, use `boxIdToRightEdgeMap` to  locate the `rightEdge` value  in the `rightEdgeMap` .

**Use case box 4 is resized:**

```
int xValOfRightEdge=boxIdToRightEdgeMap.get(4);
```

remove 4 from `rightEdgeMap's` value arrayList using `xValOfRightEdge`.
And insert 4 in appropriate `rightEdgeMap's` value-arryList.

**Query within searching box:**

One way could be, to store the edges in a `NavigableMap<Integer,List<Integer>>` , where `key= Y` coordinate of `rightEdge`, `value= list` of `rightEdges` that fall in that Y coordinate. Now get `subMap( minY ,MaxY)` . minY and MaxY refers to searchingBox's min and max Y values. Sorting this submap decendingly you get the first entry as answer.

**Use case box 4 is moved:** 
No need to change in any map.

**Observation:**
*The time complexity is noticeably less.*

Comment: The distance to the "Reference Rect" from any point inside searching box  must be uniform. 
1. The 1st searching box has to grow above and below the top and bottom of the "Reference Rect". 
2. The 2 corners of the searching box has to be convexly curved so that the diagonal distance from "Reference Rect "is always the same inside the searching box

Comment: Yes you are correct, I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store all rectangles in an array and match the nearest coordinates of other rectangles:

Suppose array of rectangles is:
   `Rectangle[][4] rectangles = {{left, top, right, bottom}, {left, top, right, bottom}}`

Now if you need to find the first rectangle on the left side, simple compare right of each rectangle in the array with the left of reference rectangle. Largest value of right of rectangle will give you the first rectangle on left side.

```
Rectangle referenceRectangle[4] = {rrl, rrt, rrr, rrb}
int max = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < rectangles.length ; i++)
{
  if(rectangles[0][2] < referenceRectangle[0])
  {
    if(rectangles[0][2] > max)
    {
      max = rectangles[0][2];
      //Note the Index or maintain the list of rectangles.
    }   
  }
}
```

Similarly, other rectangles can be found out.